# using big-Omega to prove t(n) = n + n logn^2 is/= Omega(5n + 9nlogn^5)

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I am having trouble solving a proof. Where t(n) <= c(5n + 9nlogn^5), c being a constant. In general, Big Omega is the opposite of Big O in that it is the best case scenerio and looks for the lower bound. So there exists a c and and n0 such that n >= n0. But I am uncertain how to apply this to the proof and how to manipulate the constants in the equation to find c and n0 and to prove that t(n) is `Omega(5n + 9nlogn^5)`.

```
t(n) = n + n logn^2 is/= Omega(5n + 9nlogn^5)
```

Could anyone offer some insight on how to do this type of problem?

Comment: Neither Ο nor Ω describe worst or best case behavior. They just describe equivalence classes of functions with an equivalent limiting behavior by an upper bound (Ο) and a lower bound (Ω), respectively. You can as well use Ω to describe the lower bound of worst case scenarios and Ο to describe the upper bound of best case scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of Big-Omega, `f(n) is Ω( g(n) )` mathematically means
`0 ≤ C⋅g(n) ≤ f(n)`, for any constant `C > 0` and `n > n'`
Here,
`f(n) = n + n⋅log(n²) = n + 2⋅n⋅log(n)` and
`g(n) = 5n + 9n⋅log(n⁵) = 5n + 45n⋅log(n)`.

and we want to prove `0 ≤ C * g(n) ≤ f(n)`.

Now, taking `C = 1/45`,

`(1/45)⋅(5n + 45n*log(n)) = (n/9 + n⋅logn) <= (n + 2n⋅logn)`

Hence, `0 ≤ (1/45)⋅g(n) ≤ f(n)` ⇒ `f(n) is Ω(g(n)) for C = 1/45 and n > 0`.